# Kotlin functional find single element

Tags: kotlin, filter, functional-programming, kotlin-function-type

I am relatively new to Kotlin and I try to overcome a special case.
I am filtering a books store and want to verify that the length of the obtained list is exactly one unit shorter than the original one. Further I need to verify that the discarded element is under a specific state. Here is my example:

```
  fun BookStoreVerified(bookStore: BookStore): Boolean {

    val specialChapter = bookStore.stores
      .flatMap { it.books }
      .flatMap { it.chapters }.filter { it != null && it.state == Chapter.SPECIAL }

    val total = bookStore.stores
      .flatMap { it.books }
      .flatMap { it.chapters }
      .filterNotNull()

   val finalChapters = book.stores
      .flatMap { it.books }
      .flatMap { it.chapters }
      .filter { it != null && it.state.isCorrect }

    return (finalChapters.size + specialChapterFigure.size == total.size) && (specialChapter.size == 1)
  }
```

My question is if there is a smarter way to compute the above operation. I would like to know if ander a scope like filter, map can we make reference to the previous object? ( get the length of the original list for instance ?)

Comment: I don't really see the question here.

Comment: See question above please.

Comment: What do you think is the problem with the code as is?

Comment: I would like to know better and more efficient manner to compute it. Want ot master funcitonal kotlin skills. Thanks!

Comment: just thinking about performance, the `flatMap` operation creates a brand new List every time, so you may want to compute it once, save it in a variable, and reuse it for subsequent operations (assuming you don't modify it in the meantime)

Comment: it would be a bit easier to see what is the best scenario if we could see the BookStore, Book and Chapter objects (I'm assuming those are the names).

Answer (score 1):

You have `Book`s where each `Book` contains a list of `Chapter`s. You want to partition chapters from all the books according to some criteria.

With this in mind the [partition](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html) function can be useful:

```kotlin
data class Chapter(val state: String)
data class Book(val chapters: List<Chapter>? = null)

fun main() {

    val books = listOf(
        Book(),
        Book(chapters = listOf(Chapter("a"), Chapter("SPECIAL"))),
        Book(chapters = listOf(Chapter("c"), Chapter("d")))
    )

    val (specialChs, regularChs) = books
        .flatMap { it.chapters ?: emptyList() }
        .partition { it.state == "SPECIAL" }


    println(specialChs) // [Chapter(state=SPECIAL)]
    println(regularChs) // [Chapter(state=a), Chapter(state=c), Chapter(state=d)]
}
```

Now that you have `specialChs` and `regularChs`, you can [check](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/check.html) whatever invariants you want.

For example:

```kotlin
check(specialChs.size == 1 && specialChs.first().state == 
"SPECIAL")
```

Edit: It is possible to abstract away the existence of null chapters inside a `Book`:

```kotlin
data class Book(val chapters: List<Chapter>? = null) {
    val safeChapters: List<Chapter>
        get() = chapters ?: emptyList()
}
```

then in your code you can `flatMap { it.safeChapters }` instead of `.flatMap { it.chapters ?: emptyList() }`

Comment: I really need the list to have nullable elements. This comes from an  existin @Entity in my code.

Comment: That is unfortunate, I amended the answer.

Comment: I was not aware of the check functinality. In case this is not true it will throw an exception right ?

Comment: Yep, an `IllegalStateException` . It is just a convenience, use it if exception makes sense in the context.

Comment: Ok thanks. Well I think that you used the partition instead.